# How to get access to localhost as root in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, localhost

what should be done to be able to get access to localhost in terminal.

1. what programs should be installed?
2. And how to get to directory of localhost as root like root@localhost?

Comment: Run the command `sudo su` and enter your password.

Comment: What do you mean by "access to localhost" and "directory of localhost"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, The internet support several protocols: http,ftp, mail, ...
So the first thing your computer need is a server that speek one of thouse protocols. A non-standard way is install samba server and play with it's config file.